# How to convert videos to ogg and mp4 and store in the database

Tags: html, database, video, converters

How can I convert a video to ogg and mp4 and automatically store it in the database?
E.g., if a user uploads an mp4 video, it will have to convert the video to ogg as well and store it in the database.
Can't find anything about this!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried this yet, but maybe it works ;)

[This](https://github.com/donmelton/video-transcoding-scripts)

Answer (score -1):

Right now i don't think any automatic tool is there to convert ogg or any other format.

You can convert the mp4 to ogg format by using any free software or converter to do this job.

You can use Miro video converter 
http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/

and BTW it's FREE and also very good for mobile device encoding.